# How to remove the additional info before the logging message itself?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, syslog

I'm using Apache Log4j logger (import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) in order to send messages to a syslog server in JSON format.

The message that I sent is something like that:

```
{"id":"1"}
```

However, in the syslog server I received:
**Feb 14 10:33:27 localhost** {"id":"1"}

How do I remove this additional info before the message itself, (**Feb 14 10:33:27 localhost**)?

My logger config

```
private Logger configureLogger(String appenderName, String loggerName, SyslogAppender syslogAppender) {
    try {
        if (syslogAppender != null) {
            syslogAppender.start();
            getConfig().addAppender(syslogAppender);
            AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[]{AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(appenderName, null, null)};
            LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", Level.DEBUG, loggerName,
                    "true", refs, null, getConfig(), null);
            loggerConfig.addAppender(syslogAppender, null, null);
            getConfig().removeLogger(loggerName);
            getConfig().addLogger(loggerName, loggerConfig);
            getContext().updateLoggers();
            return getContext().getLogger(loggerName);
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred while configuring syslog settings");
        LOGGER.trace("Exception: ", e);
        throw e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my SyslogAppender config

```
private SyslogAppender createSyslogAppender(ReportingSendProtocolType protocol, ReportingFacilityType reportingFacilityType, String host, int port, boolean ignoreExceptions, String appenderName, Configuration config) {
    return SyslogAppender.createAppender(host,
            port,
            protocol.name(),
            null,
            0,
            0,
            true,
            appenderName,
            true,
            ignoreExceptions,
            Facility.toFacility(reportingFacilityType.name()),
            null,
            Rfc5424Layout.DEFAULT_ENTERPRISE_NUMBER,
            true,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            true,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            config,
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
            null,
            new LoggerFields[]{},
            true); //false
}
```

Comment: A timestamp and hostname is usually added by **syslogd** when writing messages to a file. What syslogd are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to configure the PatternLayout that its simply the message format.

I.E:

This pattern is goint to show you the Timestamp and the class (represented by "t")

```
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t]
```

If you want only show the message, the pattern looks like:

```
%msg%n
```

More information about the Pattern: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

In order to add to your code, you have got an example here:

```
    PatternLayout layout= PatternLayout.createLayout(PATTERN, null, null, Charset.defaultCharset(),false,false,null,null);
        Appender appender=ConsoleAppender.createAppender(layout, null, null, "CONSOLE_APPENDER", null, null);
        appender.start();
    getConfig().addAppender(appender);
```

Hope its usefull

Comment: I added to the question the  SyslogAppender config. where do I put the pattern %msg%n?

Comment: In the docs http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0-beta7/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/SyslogAppender.html
_italic_format - If set to "RFC5424" the data will be formatted in accordance with RFC 5424. Otherwise, it will be formatted as a BSD Syslog record._italic_

To set the standard output for syslog

Comment: As @DevJV remarked, the `SyslogAppender` uses a specific layout described in [RFC 5424](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424). Unlike the `ConsoleAppender` this can not be changed. The specific format that shows up in the log file depends on the Syslogd configuration. E.g. Systemd-journald can format the message as JSON.

Comment: So it means that I cannot remove this additional info if Im using SyslogAppender, correct ?

Comment: No, it just means that Log4j is not responsible for the formatting and you should look into your syslogd documentation. E.g. for RSyslogd check [the template configuration](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I override SyslogAppender and buildLayout() like below.

```
public class MySyslogAppender extends SyslogAppender {
    @Override
    public Layout<ILoggingEvent> buildLayout() {
        if (suffixPattern == null) {
            suffixPattern = DEFAULT_SUFFIX_PATTERN;
        }
        PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
        layout.setPattern(suffixPattern);
        layout.setContext(getContext());
        layout.start();
        return layout;
    }
}
```

And apply this class at logback.xml

```
<appender name="syslog" class="MySyslogAppender"/>
```

It can apply suffixPattern normally and no prefix of time and host anymore. I think it is also useful if create MySyslogAppender programmatically.

Comment: The question was about Log4j2, not Logback.